# Input returning string when it needs to be used as an integer

Tags: python, indentation

So like I'm trying to teach myself python by doing basic coding challenges. I'm trying to make the program take the user input then do the operations then output the correct result. Instead it just ignores all the operations. **I think it had something to do with indents but... I'm like 30 minutes deep into learning python so I really have 0 idea.** Could someone please explain why and where this isn't working?

```py
var = input("pick number!= ")


def fizzbuzz(var):
    operand0 = 3
    operand1 = 5
    if var % operand0 == 0 and var % operand1 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"
    if var % operand0 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    if var % operand1 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    else:
        return var


print(fizzbuzz(var))
```

Output:

````
  File "****", line 17, in <module>
    print(fizzbuzz(var))
  File "****", line 7, in fizzbuzz
    if var % operand0 == 0 and var % operand1 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting```
````

Comment: What is the input you are entering and what is the output program is giving and what is your expected output? What is `inp` in first `if`?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Typo: change inp to var in first if.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to take the [tour] and read [ask]. You don't even describe what you see when running this or how you come to suspecting indentation being the culprit.

Comment: @anuragal oops ``inp`` is supposed to read ``var`` but the output i recieve is: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****", line 17, in <module>
    print(fizzbuzz(var))
  File "*****", line 7, in fizzbuzz
    if var % operand0 == 0 and var % operand1 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your program I get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<stdin>", line 4, in fizzbuzz
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

This is because `var = input("pick number!= ")` makes `var` **a string, not a number**. And `%` doesn't work on strings the same way it does on numbers — see https://pyformat.info/#simple.

To convert your input to a number, you can use `var = int(input("..."))` or similar.

This is a difference between Python 2 and 3 — in Python 2, `input()` evaluated the argument rather than treating it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `python3` you need to convert the `input` `string` into `integer` and in your first `if` statement instead of `inp`(which is undefined) you should use `var`: Try:

```
var = int(input("pick number!= "))


def fizzbuzz(var):
    operand0 = 3
    operand1 = 5
    if var % operand0 == 0 and var % operand1 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"
    if var % operand0 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    if var % operand1 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    else:
        return var


print(fizzbuzz(var))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `int var` instead of int and also
Try this:

```
operand0 = 3
operand1 = 5
if var % operand0 == 0 and inp % operand1 == 0:
return "FizzBuzz"
elif var % operand0 == 0:
return "Fizz"
elif var % operand1 == 0:
return "Buzz"
else:
return var
```